# Swift callback function for draw()?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ondraw

I have a `customView` where I overwrite [`drawRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect). I also have some cases, where I want to display a UILabel ontop of my `customView`:

```
if self.ticks.count < 50 {
    self.label.frame = self.bounds
    self.label.text = "This chart requires 50 or more ticks.\nKeep Ticking."
    self.addSubview(label)
}
```

However if I call this code before the [`drawRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect) is called, then my label doesn't show up. Is there a callback method like `viewDidDraw` or something?

### EDIT

Someone asked for it, so here is all the code that is now doing what I need it to do. I think the answer to the question is to override `layoutSubviews`.

```
@IBDesignable open class  CustomView: UIView {
    @objc open var ticks:[Tick] = []
    let label = UILabel()

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    required public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    func setup(){
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.label.frame = self.bounds
        self.label.text = "This chart requires 50 or more ticks.\nKeep Ticking."
        self.label.numberOfLines = 0
        self.label.textAlignment = .center
        self.addSubview(label)
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        self.label.frame = self.bounds
    }

    @objc open func setSessions(sessions:[Session]){
        self.ticks = []
        for session in sessions.reversed(){
            if self.ticks.count < 250{
                self.ticks = self.ticks + (session.getShots() as! [Shot])
            }else{
                break
            }
        }
        if self.ticks.count < 50 {
            self.label.isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.label.isHidden = true
        }
        self.bringSubview(toFront: self.label)
    }

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let width = rect.width - 10;
        let height = rect.height - 10;
        let center = CGPoint(x: width/2+5, y: height/2+5)
        let big_r = min(width, height)/2

        context.setLineWidth(1.5)
        UIColor.white.setStroke()

        //draw the rings
        for i in stride(from: 1, to: 7, by: 1){
            let r = big_r * CGFloat(i) / 6.0;
            context.addArc(center:center, radius:r, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*Double.pi), clockwise: false)
            context.strokePath()
        }

        //draw the ticks
        if self.ticks.count > 49 {
            UIColor.red().setFill()
            for (i, tick) in self.ticks.prefix(250).enumerated(){
                let radius = min((100.0-CGFloat(shot.score))/30.0 * big_r, big_r);

                let x = Utilities.calculateX(tick, radius)
                let y = Utilities.calculateY(tick, radius)

                let point = CGPoint(x: x+center.x,y: y+center.y)
                context.addArc(center:point, radius:CGFloat(DOT_WIDTH/2), startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*Double.pi), clockwise: false)
                context.fillPath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no UIView method `onDraw` so what are you "overwriting" exactly?

Comment: dis you try adding the label as subview in initWithFrame: or any custom init: you are using ,and initially make it hidden, and whenever necessary just tweak the hidden property ? NB: if you are using nib, awake from nib is a good place to instantiate and add the label as subview, even if you add the label in nib you dont need to instantiate or add as subview, tweaking the hidden value when time is right :)

Comment: For some reason adding it in the custom init isn't working. The code is being called, but no label is showing up...

Comment: haha, the frame is set to 0,0,0,0

Comment: so the next question is how do I know when the frame is resized?

Comment: that depend on your purpose, what to do while view frame is resized.
1. resizing the label attached to the top ?
2. update drawing content ?
which one ?

Comment: Resize the label. `override open func layoutSubviews()` looks like it does the trick.

Comment: If you put the rest of your code up people will be able to help you better and will have a clearer idea of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: if you only intend to resize the label, then adding some `NSLayoutConstraint` should do the trick.

Comment: Or just set the autoresizing mask

Answer (score 1):

You can make your custom view redraw by calling setNeedsDisplay() when needed. After that, you can add the label

Comment: True. But `setNeedsDisplay()` only calls drawing code. We are looking for how trigger code after the drawing is done.

Comment: add the code after setNeedsDisplay()?? Not sure what you exactly mean by "trigger code"

Comment: If you call `setNeedsDisplay()` and then immedatiely call `updateView()`, `updateView` will run before `draw(rect:)` runs. `setNeedsDisplay()` doesn't call `draw` it just sets a flag that the view needs to be redrawn, but there are no guarantees as to when it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegation for the View class and call the delegate method at the end of the draw function. However, it seems that if you call that directly, the draw function will only end until the delegate function get processed. Which means that the code will be executed before the new drawing refresh on the screen. In that case, you may need to call it asynchronously.

```
// at end of draw function
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.delegate?.drawEnd()
}
```